# Seeing data that caused a streaming ingestion failure

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have streaming ingestion, via EventHub, setup on my cluster.  The table ingesting the data has an update policy that is transactional.

I'm wondering if/how I can see the data involved in an ingestion failure or update policy failure.  Is the message involved in the failure lost forever?  My goal is to capture messages that failed due to streaming ingestion or update policy errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.dup-next-failed-ingest command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/dup-next-failed-ingest)
It will upload the failed file to a storage of your choice.

Comment: This approach is irrelevant for streaming ingestion

Comment: Streaming in EH fallback to queued ingestion - so you could capture the failure of the queued ingestion with the .dup-next command (if it fails as well).
 In any way one can monitor failures using regular [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/monitor-batching-ingestion) and [logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/using-diagnostic-logs?tabs=ingestion#diagnostic-logs-schema)